# Initializing the document of a webBrowser and blocking until complete

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, browser

I'm using a `webBrowser` control to display log data as HTML in a custom control in a form in C#.  For the most part I'm using the DOM through `HtmlElement` objects etc.  But when I initialize the control I setup some styles by setting the `webBrowser.DocumentText` property.

My problem is that when using `webBrowser.navigate` or `webBrowser.DocumentText` these actions seem to be on a different thread internally in the `webBrowser` control.  So when I initialize my control and try to immediately add `HtmlElements` through the DOM it fails because the document hasn't initialized yet.  I could wait for the `documentComplete` event but I'm wrapping all this in a custom control and it would be bad etiquette to get someone to subscribe to an event just to make sure the control is initialized.  Accessing a web doc through the DOM however seems to block the current thread which is what I want.

Questions:

- Is there a way to tell the `webBrowser` to block until it's finished initializing its document?
- Is there a way to initialize a `webBrowser`'s document purely through DOM calls?  i.e. not using `webBrowser.navigate` or `webBrowser.DocumentText`

EDIT
I've tried this, it just blocks forever, I'm assuming for something like this to work you'd need multiple threads?:

```
this.webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");

while (this.webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me:

```
public void NavigateSynchronously(string url)
{
    this.WbrConfigurator.Navigate(url);

    while (this.WbrConfigurator.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

I suppose you are missing the DoEvents.

Answer (score 0):

```
var signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);

wb.DocumentCompleted += (o, args) => signal.Set();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => wb.Navigate("about:blank"));

signal.WaitOne();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give this a go.  Though I'm pretty sure I tried something similar with AutoResetEvent and the DocumentCompleted event.  I think it blocked the main thread so the event never triggered.  But I'll check it out again.

Comment: Again has anyone tried this out? Using these methods just blocks the main thread so the DocumentCompleted event never fires which means reset.Set() is never executed.